Is it ok for my immortal character to date a child?
For some context, my character Mirao, is immortal, but she was cursed at 14 to be 14 forever. She's about 986-ish years old and her girlfriend is 15. Is this okay or should I scrap this part? They're just side characters.

@Laurel: I don't think the referred answer answer, about romance and sexual feelings between different species, provided any good answers to this question. I don't think it is a duplicate. "Immortal" does not imply the immortal character is non-human, this is more about whether an "immortal" human 986 years old can date a child the same apparent age as herself. I think this is a unique question.

@Amadeus I disagree. The other question mentions vampires, which are the quintessential immortal. Are they human?—it doesn't matter. This question doesn't even call the immortal character a human. The distinction between what constitutes a species in fantasy (or sci-fi) is completely a preference, since there's no science involved, though there is a good argument that biological mechanisms so drastically different and inhuman (like immortality) would justify labeling them a separate species.

Is it wrong for an immortal 986 old who is stuck in the body (and in the mental state?!?) of a 14 year old to date a 15 year old? This is a good question. A question which a good work of fantasy might want to explore in greater detail.
There is a lot that can happen in a work of fiction that is morally reprehensible. I would argue that the vast majority of acclaimed fictional literature depicts a lot of immoral acts being committed. Lies, treason, abuse, murder, warcrimes, genocide...there is no subject so risky that it should be off-limits for a good author. Whether or not that makes the work itself morally reprehensible depends on how exactly it portrays these events. When a work depicts them in a way that condemns and not glorifies them, then it can get away with pretty much anything.
So you should ask yourself if there is anything that could be morally, ethically or interpersonally wrong about this relationship, and if you find something, address these concerns in your work. There are several ways to do that:

Show, don't tell, how the power dynamic in this relationship works and how it affects the characters
Have other characters raise concerns about this relationship
Raise concerns from the perspective of the narrator


What could be wrong about this relationship? Well, the reason why our society shuns romantic relationships with a large age difference is not because such couples look weird. Our society has grown past the bigotry of telling people who they are allowed to love based on physical characteristics. No, it's because a large age difference implies a very different level of life experience and experience with navigating romantic relationships. This puts the older partner in a position that allows them to take advantage of the younger partner.
And here we are talking about someone who has the equivalent of over 10 whole lifetimes of life experience. How many relationships did she have in her life? How many couples did she witness coming together and falling apart again over all those centuries? This is all knowledge she can use to manage her next romance.
Compare that to the experience of a teenager who is probably in their first serious romantic relationship. Teenage romance is awkward. Teenagers in love don't understand their own feelings. They understand even less about the feelings of their partner. They lack the ability to properly communicate the little they understand. They don't know what to expect or what is expected of them to make the relationship work for both of them.
Now it might seem like a good arrangement at first when one partner is older and knows all of that, so they can teach the younger partner all of these things. Some societies have tried that. But the problem is the power dynamic that comes with such a master-and-student relationship. It is very difficult for the older partner to not take advantage of the younger partner, even if they try not to.
Which is why aeons of humans learning to love each other has lead to the consensus that it's best to learn together with people who are just as inexperienced as oneself. Yes, you are going to get hurt, but at least you are going to get hurt by someone who is in the same position as you are.

I'm 30 and I have some hobbies where I frequently interact with teenagers and despite having quite a lot in common, it is unimaginable to be on same page enough to even dream about romantic interest. A 1000 years old being genuinely romantically attracted to 15 years old would be hard stop for mine suspension of disbelief. But, it would make good story to explore what motivesthe immortal has in engaging in such relationship. Struggling with eternal puberty? Desperation of not finding more suitable partners? Feeling young again? To do this right, relationship have to be very "non-standard"

Two considerations.
One, you are allowed to portray problematic situations, on the condition you don't frame them as okay (or to be on the safe side, in a story aimed at young readers it's a good idea to downright frame them as not okay). In fact you very much need some situations that are not okay in your story, lest you wouldn't have a story in the first place. Attempting to murder a whole family (and succeeding with the parents, while the toddler survives) is an extremely bad thing to do, but nobody seems to mind that Rowling had such a scene in her book. (Whereas I very much do criticise her for revealing that Dumbledore deliberately groomed his students as willing cannon fodder, and framing that as a good thing. A headmaster's job is to keep his students safe, not to manipulate them into getting themselves killed.)
Two, to what extent the situation is problematic heavily depends on what exactly it means in your story to be fourteen forever - which you aren't giving enough detail to tell. I'm thinking of Ysabell, the adopted daughter of Death who appears in the Discworld novel Mort. When Mort asks how old she is, she says she's sixteen, then clarifies she has been sixteen for thirty-five years, and starts crying from frustration over it.
Technically, Ysabell was born fifty years ago and has lived for fifty years, but she is still an akward, angsty teenager who hasn't matured a day over sixteen. All she has to show for the extra time is that she's learned to manage Death's complicated accounting books. Having lived all her life in Death's isolated house, she's even less socially experienced than an ordinary sixteen-year-old who's lived in a village like Mort. She's as far from a fifty-year-old woman grooming a naive young lad as you can get. If you look for an unhealthy power imbalance in their relationship, there's nothing to find. Maybe it's even Mort who has a bit of an upper hand.
On the other hand, if there was a worldly, independent fifty-year-old with only the looks of someone who is sixteen... that'd be a vastly different situation.
So make sure you know, at least vaguely, how it works in your world, what kind of life the immortal character has lived for those thousand years, what kind of capital and power they wield and what they don't. Would they be able to manipulate the teenager with their millenium-honed social skills? Then perhaps rather not, at least not in a condoning tone. Are the two still pretty much equals, with one of them simply having a bunch of horrific stories about the middle ages to tell? Go ahead.

A lot (really, a lot) has been written about the ethics of a similar romantic relationship between the main characters in the Twilight series. There we have a smaller age gap, a teenage girl (17, I think) and a 100 something year old vampire stuck with the body of a teenage boy. This already shows that you can do this and not only get away with it, but be immensely commercially successful.
Twilight has been critized a lot based on ethical grounds, but it is not just the age issue. The relationship is depicted with many aspects that make it highly abusive, yet it is clearly all meant to be read as romantic. Thus, many people see a high risk that the books/films might severely distort some teenage fans ideas of how relationships should be, and thereby do significant harm.
Let's contrast this with another age-gap relationship in contemporary very successful media, albeit without the apparent/real age discrepancy angle. In the Game of Thrones book, Dani is a 14 year old princess married off to Drogo, a 30 something Khan of Mongol-style horse nomands. There even is a sex scene of the marriage being consumated! Again, this shows clearly that this is something people can get away with and be commercially very successful.
The depiction of this relationship is, to my knowledge, not nearly as controversial. The main difference is that it is presented as in a matter-of-fact way. It is stuff that happens, not stuff that is ok-to-happen or even praise-worthy to happen.
Alright, so you cleary can have such a relationship in your novel. Should you?
My guiding principle for a writing a relationship like you describe in a young adult setting would be: If a teenage reader identifies with Mirao's girlfriend, is there a risk that this leaves them more vulnerable to being groomed?

Enough of has been said about the ethics of the question, so addressing the writing part of it:
If you present something that could be construed as distasteful or even deplorable about Mirao, then you should expect your reader to find Mirao to be distasteful or deplorable.
If that's the reaction you want, then your work is done. If that's not the reaction you want, then you'll have to convince the reader otherwise. The more complicated and polarizing the situation, the more convincing it will take. If Mirao is a side character that you don't want to spend a lot of time on, don't create a situation that requires a lot of time.
You need to decide what's best for the story. If you're a character writer, sometimes side characters waltz into your story and demand spotlight. If you're a plot writer, side characters can throw all kinds of hurdles and hiccups into your finely-crafted storyline. Sometimes that's great; a sidebars/side characters is exactly what the story needs. And sometimes it's exactly wrong; they're a distraction from what you really want your readers to be reading about: the main character(s). Or depending on the voice and themes of your story, that aspect of Mirao might also spark curiosity in your reader. Woah, she's a thousand years old but looks like a kid? Yeah that'll complicate your career and love life! How does she manage that??? Leaving it untold could bereave the reader.
It's up to your author instinct. Is Mirao (or this aspect of Mirao) worth it; to the story, and/or to you as a writer?

Being friends would be fine, but being lovers is probably considered child pornography. The actual age of Mirao makes her an adult no matter her appearance. The actual age of friend makes her a minor (at least in the USA) incapable of consent to any form of intimate contact.
I'd either convert them to best friends, or scrap any romantic or sexual contact. Best friends can hold hands and hug. They can profess love for each other. That's about it. I would not include any kissing or other content that suggests it goes any further than that.

"incapable" isn't the right word. More like "not allowed to". "Incapable" implies they are completely physically unable to say "sure, I'm okay with that", which they aren't, but the law says that their "okay" is invalid for obvious reasons.

@AustinOverton They are by law considered incapable of giving consent. Not all forms of "incapable" have to do with being physically incapable.

My idea of definition of some words needs work.

Wait, do you have laws preventing teenagers from dating? I'm asking because in my corner of the world, it's not only perfectlly legal but considered absolutely normal for two teens under the age of consent to kiss, or hug around the waist like a pair of friends never would, play with each other's hair, sit in one another's lap and such. (The age of consent is fifteen, by the way, so the two characters would be legally in the clear to make love as well, unless Mirao's "fourteen forever" means that she isn't allowed to consent. But the question never mentions lovemaking, just dating.)

@Divizna I presumed "dating" as used here is a euphemism that involves sexual contact; because if sexual contact is excluded I don't think it makes sense to even ask the question. Yes, underage girls can kiss and hug; but that is not legally considered sexual contact. In America that is not illegal, to my knowledge. I think the OP must be referring to something more sexual  than that.

Extreme power imbalance
The problem isn't that one character is umpty-bajillion years old. The problem is the other one is only 15.
Consider the human brain is still developing into a person's mid-20s. This person is not an adult, and as Amadeus states is not capable of giving legal consent, nor would they be capable of NOT being manipulated by a thousand year old being.
Your millennial being would be VERY aware of the imbalance, so would your readers. Your story has to 'play' in your readers heads where this would be coded as predatory.

Changes occurring between ages 18 and 25 are essentially a continued process of brain development that started during puberty. When you’re 18, you’re roughly halfway through the entire stage of development. The prefrontal cortex doesn’t have nearly the functional capacity at age 18 as it does at 25.
... Some people may have major struggles with impulsive decisions and
planning behavior to reach a goal. The brain’s reward system tends to
reach a high level of activation during puberty, then gradually drifts
back to normal activation when a person reaches roughly the age of 25.
Adults over the age of 25 tend to feel less sensitive to the influence
of peer pressure and have a much easier time handling it.
MentalHealthDaily

From my own family (redneck cousins), marriage at 15 is far from happily ever after. It is  something that is necessary because they got pregnant and things needed to be hurried along or be cut off from the family. I can't un-see how it works in real life.
A teenage crush
It doesn't matter if the 15yo has a crush, or has been sexually active before. Being under the age of consent (in our world) and clearly having little to no independent life-experience means they don't have the capacity to navigate the relationship as an adult could.
I don't want to tell you what to write, but someone who is 1000 years old can afford to wait another decade (1% of their lifetime) for their ideal to 'grow up'. Presumably they have seen the full human life cycle many times before. They would understand the reason to wait to drink the wine.
However for a 15 year old, waiting 10 years is 2/3rds of their entire life. See the problem? They were 5 years old that same number of years ago. To the 15 year old, waiting a decade would be literally more than half their life. There is no way to make this math look un-sketchy, and you are exaggerating it exponentially.
A 25yo is as different to a 15yo, as a 15yo is to a 5yo. (Ick!)
You can have a headstrong 15 year old who feels they are ready, and a millennial being who knows they are not. There is a lot of story-tension that can be mined here, a whole arc where the ancient can mask their feelings to the frustration of the teen – and ultimately an arc where the teen is allowed to show they actually aren't as mature as they want to be.
The millennial's biggest fear might be that the 15 year old changes, or grows to resent the situation, or becomes bored with someone 'old and stagnant' who will not continue to grow and develop as they will. They would miss the depth of a mutual relationship where they contributed equally. It would forever be unbalanced. They could become restless (and after a 1000yo lover, where do they go? Ruined for mortal relationships but craving something even more exciting...). If this has happened before, it could be a red line they won't cross.
You say they are not your main characters, and maybe that's better. They could be in a guardian/ward relationship that can't progress (at the moment), then reveal the tension for more. A complicated dynamic might be more interesting to the reader.

That you felt the need to Ask seems to clearly show that no, that's not OK, nor in 1,000 years could it ever be.
Can you say why you use '986-ish' instead of 'about 1,000'? Doesn't the difference suggest there's something to hide?
Why do you not yourself address the issue of her being either 14 forever, or about 986-ish years old or somehow both?
Are you suggesting '14 forever' means she gains no knowledge or wisdom after age 14, or merely that she's stuck at that stage of physical development?
In most European countries, any guy's girlfriend being 15 should prevent them sharing real shenanigans but the details are too complex to even list here.
My suggestion is that if you feel any need to Ask whether that's OK then no, it's not… and doubly so if they're just side characters.
